# How can I define type in ts?

Tags: typescript

```
type TagProps = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  color: string;
};

  const tags: TagProps[] = data.properties.tag.multi_select;

//

{
id: "xxxx"
name: "xxx"
},
{
id: "xxxx"
name: "xxx"
},
{
id: "xxxx"
name: "xxx"
}


   <section className="mt-2 flex items-start space-x-2">
          {tags.map(({ id, name }: TagProps) => (
            <h1 className="w-30 rounded-md bg-sky-200 px-2 py-1 dark:bg-sky-700" key={id}>
              {name}
            </h1>
          ))}
   </section>
```

I got an error 'Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'TagProps[]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TagProps'

Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: Perhaps because `data.properties.tag.multi_select` is of type `string[]`?

Comment: I defined the typing like this.
const tags: TagProps= data.properties.tag.multi_select;
not working..

Comment: Maybe changing the line to `const tags: TagProps[] = data.properties.tag.multi_select.map(txt=>({id:txt,name:txt,color:""}));` can help you to understand the problem

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now we don't have access to `data` so we can't say for sure what the problem is.